# preg_match: check if it doesn't includes a word

Tags: php, preg-match

Code:

```
if (!preg_match("https://www.youtube.com/channel/~i", $l1)) {
    $l1 = $l1 . "?sub_confirmation=1";
  }
```

My query is, if a link doesn't contain a ?sub_confirmation=1, it is going to be added. But if a link already contains it, it shouldn't be added! How to do that ?

Comment: Your regex is incomplete, you need a `~` in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **strpos()**

**Example -**

```
  $link = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/~i";
  $search = '?sub_confirmation=1';
  if (strpos($link, $search) === false) {
   $link =  $link.$search;
  }
  echo $link;
```

**EDIT**

if you want only for specific url (in your case only for youtube channel urls) then add one more if condition like example below.

**Try this**

```
 $link = "youtube.com/watch?v=example";
  $search = '?sub_confirmation=1';
  $searchUrl = "youtube.com/channel";
  if (strpos($link, $searchUrl) !== false && strpos($link, $search) === false) {
   $link =  $link."".$search;
}
echo $link;
```

Comment: It works, the problem here is that there are not only links like that, but they still all get added ?sub_confirmation=1

Comment: can you show me an example of that type of link @Leeroy

Comment: or an instagram link

Comment: see my updated answer @Leeroy and tell me if any issue come.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if( ! preg_match('#sub_confirmation=1#is', $l1 ) )
{
    $l1 = $l1 . "?sub_confirmation=1";
}
```

even so, i recommended you play with [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


if (strpos($url,'YourWord') !== false) {
    echo 'Word exists.';
    //your code for not adding the link
} else {
    echo 'Word doesn't exist.';
    //your code for adding the link
}
```